# How to append to multiple files quickly while using little memory in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, memory, bigdata

I'm trying to manipulate some data in a CSV file which on average, the file can be 20GBs in size, worst-case scenario, 200GB.

The data in this file is randomised but I need to process the data in groups. Luckily the unsorted file contains information I can use to group the data.

What I am doing currently:

1. Reading the original file using File.ReadLines. My understanding is this only reads one line at a time meaning I'm not storing the whole file in RAM?

2a) I was creating a file for each group and then writing the line to that file. If the file already existed, I would then append to it.

2b) The method in 2a was slow which I assumed was due to doing a lot of IO calls. What I have done now is store each StreamWriter for each group in a Dictionary so I can keep the stream open at all times. This has sped the operation up massively.

The only issue with 2b is it's keeping a lot of data in RAM. For this 1.2GB file (very small compared to the average file), it's already using 2.6GB RAM after 8mins of runtime so hasn't finished yet.

My guess is this is due to the StreamWriter keeping the written data in the buffer? I've tried flushing the stream after each write but this has done nothing.

How can I use such huge files while using little RAM while being relatively fast? (Reading 5GB in <=1hr preferably if possible).

Edit: This 1.29GB file was executed in 23mins and used 3GB RAM.

Comment: 200GB csv files? Why you are working with these monsters, why do they exist at all? This data belongs into a database.

Comment: _Memory-mapped files?_

Comment: *"I've tried flushing the stream after each write but this has done nothing."* -- Do you mean that you tried calling the method [`StreamWriter.Flush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush) after each [`StreamWriter.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline), and it had no effect at the size of the used memory? How many are the small files that you are keeping open during the whole operation?

Comment: @TimSchmelter _"This data belongs into a database"_ - and how does one get it in the database in the first place?  For all we know the OP is writing an **ETL** app. CSV is a close cousin of EDI-type files including HL7, which are the most popular form of EAI (XML and JSON are no where to be seen).  https://www.amazon.com.au/Enterprise-Service-Bus-Theory-Practice-ebook/dp/B004P5NPQ2

Comment: ...and SQL Server allows you to export data as CSV so there's that.

Comment: @MickyD it also allows you to IMport csv.

Comment: @MickyD: How do you know what kind of app OP is writing? It wasn't mentioned.

Comment: _"How can I use such huge files while using little RAM while being relatively fast?"_ - you can't. I second Tim in that your best bet would be to import the data to a database and then do calculations / processing based on that, so you can use the advantages of indexing etc.

Comment: @TimSchmelter _"How do you know what kind of app OP is writing? **It wasn't mentioned**"_ - exactly, so how can one conclude _where_ the data belongs?

Comment: Come on Mickey. Processing 200GB worth of CSV Data ... that's not a long shot to come up with "better use a database". I agree that OP should clearify, though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is raw data we are recieving from our clients which is generated by some machine. We are also having to do quite a lot of maths on it so wouldn't be suitable for a database as we declare quite a few variables etc. Someone had wrote something with it before in a database but the code was soo bad and hard to maintain, looping through the data multiple times instead of caching in a variable due to having to work with tables.

Comment: @MickyD Maybe? I don't know too much of those systems but we are basically wanting to group all the data which will then be compressed into a 40MB file (already done). So we don't want to store all the raw data but compress the groups into an average calculation.

Comment: @Fildor 200 GB is common to the ETL EAI world, such files are not a problem.  Were you thinking of JSON?

Comment: @MickyD No. That's just something I'd jump to. But OP updated, meanwhile. So _maybe_ other solutions are just as viable. Calculations seem to be doable "on the run", so ...

Comment: @Fildor yea. They are only basic calculations. The slowest part of the operation is ordering them into groups. Once they are in a group, 1.2GBs can be processed on a Core i7 in about 3mins. The grouping is what I wish to increase speed on. I had previously used an external merge sort but this took about an hour. Now with putting groups into their own files, means it only takes 1/3rd of the time. If I can reduce the RAM usage at least, this will be good enough for the begining so as we can use larger files. RAM usage when grouping is the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

1. [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) does not read the file contents into memory. It rather creates an iterator. The file lines are read during the actual iteration.
2. Appending to multiple files can be slow, especially if you are using a hard disk drive with moving parts. You could resort to multiple passes through your main file and store as much as feasible in memory. Another potential improvement would be compression. You could store the file contents in a compressed fashion using less memory and write them to files decompressed.